# Get particular value of array from an object and sum the values

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic4

I have the following code:

```
   if (this.places.length) {
    console.log(this.places);
    var myData = this.places.map(({ points }) => points);
    var myTotal = 0;  // Variable to hold your total

    for(var i = 0, len = myData.length; i < len; i++) {
        myTotal += myData[i][1];  // Iterate over your first array and then grab the second element add the values up
    }
    console.log(myTotal);
  }
```

I have an object see [image: screenshot], from that object i need to extract all arrays, and from that arrays just a particular value, for example points.

The main goal is to sum and save all points into a new variable.
The code from abobe it's not working.

Comment: would be good if you could put the source data, a sample...

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting to calculate the total of all `points` fields in each `Place` object contanied in the `this.places` array and store the result in a new variable `myTotal` - one way to achieve that would be via [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
if (this.places.length) {

    /* The total returned by reduce() will be stored in myTotal */
    let myTotal = this.places.reduce((total, place) => {    

        /* For each place iterated, access the points field of the 
        current place being iterated and add that to the current
        running total */
        return total + place.points;

    }, 0); /* Total is initally zero */

    console.log(this.places);
    console.log(myTotal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use the forEach on the places array and add the value of the points property:

```
   if (this.places.length) {
    var myTotal = 0;  // Variable to hold your total

    places.forEach(place => myTotal = myTotal + place.points);
    console.log(myTotal);
  }
```